# How can I make sure that a user cannot login twice with the same account in PHP?

Tags: php, session, user-accounts

I have a PHP application with sessions, and want to make sure that the users don't give their credentials to third persons, which could use the account at the same time.

Is there any way to make sure that a user who logs in will kick out the first one ?

Is there also a way to view which sessions are active ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Add a `LoggedIn` field to your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can link the session id with the logged in user. Then look up if that user has a session id, if so destroy that session with that session id. Link the session name also. Then you can destroy the session cookie of that user.

```
setcookie($session_name, '', time()-3600, '/');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can have a column on their user table you check each time they try to authenticate. (authenticated: true, false). Sessions will die off and be deleted based on the time frame in php settings. If the file is gone, the session is gone.

Comment: you could also store the session id key in the users table as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question with a number of solutions - see the Google http://www.google.com/search?q=php+preventing+multiple+logins&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

The general principle is this - you need to track sessions and in your login handling code, check if a session is active for the user attempting to login - and either block that login attempt, or boot the currently logged in user in favor of the user attempting to login. There are several ways to track sessions, handle expiration, and so on. You can even do a lot of this cusotmization at a low level by overriding PHP's default session handling mechanisms - here is a handy article on the subject http://devzone.zend.com/article/141